# Converting XML to HTML and formatting it with CSS

Tags: html, css, xml

I have some data stored in XML that I want to convert to HTML and control the presentation using CSS. What is the best way to go about doing this?

My thought was to replace most of the XML tags with `<span>` tags and add appropriate class attributes. Then I can control the layout using CSS and Flexbox. For example, take this XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<funding>
    <grant>
        <project>Project 1</project>
        <funding-agency>National Aeronautics and Space Administration (NASA)</funding-agency>
        <begin-date>January 1, 2019</begin-date>
        <end-date>December 31, 2019</end-date>
        <amount>$100,000</amount>
        <pi>Alice</pi>
        <co-pi>Bob</co-pi>
        <co-pi>Carlos</co-pi>
    </grant>
    <grant>
        <project>Project 2</project>
        <funding-agency>National Science Foundation (NSF)</funding-agency>
        <begin-date>October 1, 2020</begin-date>
        <end-date>September 30, 2021</end-date>
        <amount>$500,000</amount>
        <pi>David</pi>
        <pi>Jill</pi>
    </grant>
</funding>
```

and turn it into this HTML:

```
<div class="funding">
    <section class="grant">
        <span class="project">Project 1</span>
        <span class="funding-agency">National Aeronautics and Space Administration (NASA)</span>
        <span class="begin-date">January 1, 2019</span>
        <span class="end-date">December 31, 2019</span>
        <span class="amount">$100,000</span>
        <span class="pi">Alice</span>
        <span class="co-pi">Bob</span>
        <span class="co-pi">Carlos</span>
    </section>
    <section class="grant">
        <span class="project">Project 2</span>
        <span class="funding-agency">National Science Foundation (NSF)</span>
        <span class="begin-date">October 1, 2020</span>
        <span class="end-date">September 30, 2021</span>
        <span class="amount">$500,000</span>
        <span class="pi">David</span>
        <span class="pi">Jill</span>
    </section>
</div>
```

In the end, I am hoping to get something like this:

- **Project 1**, *National Aeronautics and Space Administration (NASA)*, January 1, 2019 - December 31, 2019, $100,000. PI: Alice. Co-PIs: Bob, Carlos.
- **Project 2**. *National Science Foundation (NSF)*, October 1, 2020 - September 30, 2021, $500,000. PIs: David, Jill.

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something, but why bother to convert?

Comment: XSLT is the best way to do that.

Answer (score 2):

Please try the following XSLT based solution.

The XSLT is based on the so call *Identity Transform* pattern.

**Input XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<funding>
    <grant>
        <project>Project 1</project>
        <funding-agency>National Aeronautics and Space Administration (NASA)</funding-agency>
        <begin-date>January 1, 2019</begin-date>
        <end-date>December 31, 2019</end-date>
        <amount>$100,000</amount>
        <pi>Alice</pi>
        <co-pi>Bob</co-pi>
        <co-pi>Carlos</co-pi>
    </grant>
    <grant>
        <project>Project 2</project>
        <funding-agency>National Science Foundation (NSF)</funding-agency>
        <begin-date>October 1, 2020</begin-date>
        <end-date>September 30, 2021</end-date>
        <amount>$500,000</amount>
        <pi>David</pi>
        <pi>Jill</pi>
    </grant>
</funding>
```

**XSLT**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" encoding="utf-8" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="funding">
        <div class="funding">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </div>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="grant">
        <section class="grant">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </section>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="project | funding-agency | begin-date | end-date | amount | pi">
        <span class="{local-name()}">
            <xsl:value-of select="."/>
        </span>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Output HTML**

```
<div class="funding">
  <section class="grant">
    <span class="project">Project 1</span>
    <span class="funding-agency">National Aeronautics and Space Administration (NASA)</span>
    <span class="begin-date">January 1, 2019</span>
    <span class="end-date">December 31, 2019</span>
    <span class="amount">$100,000</span>
    <span class="pi">Alice</span>
    <co-pi>Bob</co-pi>
    <co-pi>Carlos</co-pi>
  </section>
  <section class="grant">
    <span class="project">Project 2</span>
    <span class="funding-agency">National Science Foundation (NSF)</span>
    <span class="begin-date">October 1, 2020</span>
    <span class="end-date">September 30, 2021</span>
    <span class="amount">$500,000</span>
    <span class="pi">David</span>
    <span class="pi">Jill</span>
  </section>
</div>
```

Comment: I'm familiar with XSLTs. I guess I just worded my question poorly.  Is this the best way to represent the XML data as HTML (i.e., using spans and classes)?

Comment: @Jeff, there is no direct answer to that question. It depends on how you want to present it. Linear, as in your question, HTML table, etc. But doesn't matter what an XSLT transformation is the best way to produce what you need, XML => HTML.